# Database: When to decide whether a `table relationship` is needed?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, one-to-one

I am designing a database and please have a look at the following tables

[image]

So basically, this is a fitness app. When creating the user's profile, he has to decide what his "goal**s**" are. In our app we display the list of goals as tickboxes and provide `other` field to type the "goal" if his goal is not in our list.

In our tables, the `goal_type` contains the list of goals we will be displaying to user as tick boxes.

In `profile_goal` it will contain the list of goal**s** user selected from tick boxes and if anything else, then that one as well.

Note that there is no relationship between `profile_goal` and `goal_type`. I could have make a `one to one` relationship here by creating a `foreign_key` of `goal_type` table in `profile_goal` table. The reason I didn't do this is because in someday if the developers decided to change or remove an item in `goal_type` then it will affect to thousands of users who selected that goal.
For an example there is a `goal_type` called `reduce 5kg in one month` and thousands of users have selected this; after sometime developers decide to remove it or change the goal into `eat 3 fruits this week`. Now, it is a total disaster to the people who have selected `reduce 5kg in one month`.

The downside of my current design is that imagine user has sleeted 3 `goal_types` and also has specified something for `other`. So all 4 of these goals will be available in 4 rows in `profile_goal`. If developers did change a goal in `goal_type`, then when loading the `goal_type` before the change will not be available in tick boxes and application will consider it as `other`. Then we have 2 `others` with the user's already specified `other` !!

Any idea about what is the best?

Comment: Your logic is back to front. This is precisely why you would want the 'profile_goal' column to reference the goal_id of goal_type. Note that the surrogate key id_profile_goal is redundant. You could have a perfectly good natural primary key on (patient_id,goal_id)

Comment: @Strawberry: Thank you for the reply. Basically are you suggesting that I should reference to `goal_type` in `profile_goal` by creating a foreign key? Or, delete current primary key on `profile_goal` after creating a reference of `goal_type` ? Also how about my thinking around how things will be displayed on UI, which will be clicked etc?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Remember, this is SQL - Structured Query Language. The query provides the structure.

Comment: @Strawberry: OK so, what I have to do is create a `foreign key` of `goal_type` inside `profile_goal` ?

Comment: Is it a "many:many" relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the kind of values being stored, it's tricky to answer in detail. Nonetheless, valid tables might look like this:

```
goal_type
( goal_type_id int auto_increment primary key 
, goal_type varchar(50) not null unique
)

customer_goal
(customer_id int not null
,goal_type_id int not null
,created timestamp 
,updated timestamp 
,primary key (customer_id,gial_type_id)
);
```

It seems odd to me that we would store 'a type of goal' rather than an actual goal alongside a customer_id, but we only have goal types at present; there is no 'goals' table.

Comment: by `goal_type` what I meant is the actual list of goals user can pick. If it is not listed, he can enter manually. in `profile_goal` we save this `goal_type` or the custom goal user entered. Some examples of data inside `goal_type` are `reduce 5kg in 1 month`, `run 30 minutes per day`, `workout 1 hour per day` and so on.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, goal_types is really just a list of generic goals. A customer may choose one of these to build their own fitness regime, or create goals of their own? In that case, I think your existing model is OK, but if there are other attributes associated with a generic goal, then these should also be copied over to the customer's profile. That may mean a high degree of redundancy, but it may still be the best way.

Comment: sorry but, by best way, did you mean the way i did?